# Mouse vanishes upon log in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, 16.04, mouse, hp-touchpad

I've been having this issue ever since I added an Ubuntu partition alongside Windows 10.When I boot normally its fine(its set so that when I boot I don't have to log in) but when I close the laptop lid I have to unlock it and when I do,the mouse is gone. It still works I just cant see it. If I use`sudo modeprobe -r psmouse` followed by `sudo modprobe psmouse`i can get it back, but I don't want to do that every time i log in. I'm Xubuntu 16.04 if that helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround would be to add those two commands to the end of your .profile file in your home directory...

## Edit:

To do so, go to the home directory in your terminal and type:

```
nano .xprofile
```

At the end of the file, type in:

```
modprobe -r psmouse
modprobe psmouse
```

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to write out and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit.

Comment: how would you do that? I'm sorta a noob

Comment: Go to your home directory in the terminal and type `gedit .xprofile`.  Then at the end of the file, type in `modeprobe -r psmouse` and on another new line, `modprobe psmouse`.  It occurs to me that it may or may not work, though, because you're sudoing.  It's worth a try, though, and if it doesn't work, simply remove them.